# Move files in interactive mode using 'pipe'

Tags: python

I  intent to move files in the current directory('~/Documents/') as `a.py` `b.py` `c.py` to destination file '~/Desktop'.

```
import os 
import glob
path = '~/Documents/'
os.chdir(path)
destination_path = '~/Desktop'
```

Next step to attain the files

```
file = glob.glob(path + '*.py')
source_files = file[:]
```

Set the Command

```
cmd = 'mv %s %s'
```

Iterate the files

```
for file in source_files:
    os.open(cmd %(file, destination_path))
```

Error reports

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "move-files.py", line 14, in <module>
    os.open(cmd %(file, destination_path))
TypeError: Required argument 'flags' (pos 2) not found
```

I tried to apply `eval` on `cmd` and other operatons to solve the errors.
How to move files with 'pipes' elegently?

Comment: what do you want to do? Just move files using "mv"?

Comment: yes,error found,misuse os.popen with os.oppen. @paperazzo79

Comment: I would recommend to use `os.rename` or `shutil.move` instead of `os.open`. They are much safer to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for file in source_files:
    os.open(cmd %(file, destination_path)) # misuse os.popen()
```